# Run a delegate asynchronously in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, delegates

In desktop framework I can run delegate `asynchronously` with `BeginInvoke()`:

```
Action<string> myAction;
myString = "i am string";
myAction.BeginInvoke(myString, res => {
                                myAction.EndInvoke(res);
                            }, null);
```

But in `Windows Phone` I can't do it, because must not run delegate `asynchronously`.

So, when I try run delegate with `Task`, I have error:

> Task ts = Task.Factory.StartNew(myAction);

Error: conversion of `"System.Action <string>"` to `"System.Action"` impossible. Of course, I should submit my string.

Any ideas.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a lambda to pass the parameter to your function:

```
Task ts = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myAction(myString));
```